# Row with the biggest and smallest sum in matrix

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

i have a program where i enter numbers to make a matrix, then it sums numbers in each row and print it. But i need to print even the row with the biggest and smallest sum. 
Here is a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    static int array[10][10];
    int i, j, m, n, sum = 0;

    printf("Enter the order of the matrix\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    printf("Enter the co-efficients of the matrix\n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) 
        {
            sum = sum + array[i][j] ;
        }
        printf("Sum of the %d row is = %d\n", i, sum);
        sum = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: You need to keep track of the minimum and maximum values and row numbers as you're processing the array.  Initialize the `min` to `MAXINT` and the `max` to 0.  Compare each value against `min` and `max`, updating them if they are less than or greater to, respectively.  Keep track of the rows containing the special values.  Then, at the end, just print the rows.

Comment: Initialising the max to zero will not deal correctly with an array containing negative values.   Easier to initialise the min and max using the sum of values in the first row.